# String Containment in Map Reduce

Tags: java, string, search, hadoop, bigdata

**Problem Summary** - Search a logical combination of elements in a csv string with 100s on ints : (All data is stored in HDFS to be processed using Java M/R)

Example -

```
input string - 5,7,1,19001,234567,123 (unsorted csv list)
```

search these combinations of logical AND/ORs in the input string -

```
123 and 1  

19001 or 1 or 7
```

**Overall Context** -

I have an input data set with more than 100 million records on a daily basis as HDFS files. The input file has a column called InputIds which is a csv list of long ints.

So one row would look like (I am referring to the 4th column as inputIds )

```
1\t2\t3\t45679,7890,1234567\t90\t100\t101.0.
```

Now we have a system where the user can create search strings to search the input data.
Something like -

```
userCreatedID1 - 7890 and 101 

userCreatedID2 - 7890 or 90
```

so search all UserCreatedIds in InputIds in every row.

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning search through MR??

Comment: Yes it is required for this use case

Comment: Are you aware of the consequences??